# Trouble With UIViewAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm getting in trouble on UIView Animation. When I click into one of UITextFields basically everything works fine until I select another UITextField after being selected the other one, the fields move up and down then return to the same place after I select the other UITextField.

What am I doing wrong? What I expected is to move the whole UIStackView containing my fields into up to avoid the keyboard to cover it all. Also, to keep the animation static when I click into the other UITextField, just returning to the default position when the keyboard got dismissed.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewTapped()
        setupScreen()
        setupViews()
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupScreen() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        
        self.textFieldLogin.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        self.textFieldLogin.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 190).isActive = true
        //
        self.textFieldSenha.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        self.textFieldSenha.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 190).isActive = true
        //
        self.loginButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 145).isActive = true
        self.loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        //
        self.stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        self.stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        self.stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.stackView)
        self.viewTapped()
    }
    
    private lazy var textFieldLogin: UITextField = {
        let textFieldLogin = UITextField()
        textFieldLogin.tag = 1
        textFieldLogin.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textFieldLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 3.7
        textFieldLogin.textAlignment = .center
        textFieldLogin.placeholder = "Usuário"
        textFieldLogin.backgroundColor = .white
        textFieldLogin.delegate = self
        
        return textFieldLogin
    }()
    
    private lazy var textFieldSenha: UITextField = {
        let textFieldSenha = UITextField()
        textFieldSenha.tag = 2
        textFieldSenha.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textFieldSenha.layer.cornerRadius = 3.7
        textFieldSenha.textAlignment = .center
        textFieldSenha.placeholder = "Senha"
        textFieldSenha.backgroundColor = .white
        textFieldSenha.delegate = self
        
        return textFieldSenha
    }()
    
    private lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
        let loginButton = UIButton()
        loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.8
        loginButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 19)
        loginButton.setTitle("Entrar", for: .normal)
        loginButton.setTitleColor(.systemGreen, for: .normal)
        loginButton.backgroundColor = .white
        
        return loginButton
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.textFieldLogin, self.textFieldSenha, self.loginButton])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private func viewTapped() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 5.1, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.stackView.frame.origin.y = self.stackView.frame.origin.y + 130
            self.textFieldLogin.resignFirstResponder()
            self.textFieldSenha.resignFirstResponder()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 5.1, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.stackView.frame.origin.y = self.stackView.frame.origin.y - 130
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 5.1, initialSpringVelocity: 5.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.stackView.frame.origin.y = self.stackView.frame.origin.y + 130
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Constraints are the opposite of frame animation. You cannot use both!

Comment: Should I animateY constraint instead? How it would be in code? @matt

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code into **textFieldDidBeginEditing** and everything works fine! Thank you all.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() //Think I forget this method
            self.stackView.frame.origin.y = self.stackView.frame.origin.y - 130
        }
```